# Error deploying flexipage to Scratch Org

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, metadata-api, scratch-org, flexipages

I'm having an issue trying to deploy a flexipage that uses the standard (lightning) Account list view to a scratch org.

The flexipage is a home page for an app and the list view in question is the Lightning variant i.e. Recently Viewed Accounts [RecentlyViewedAccounts]. I get the following error when trying to push:

> *Component [flexipage:filterListCard] attribute [filterName]: Error*
> *retrieving filter [RecentlyViewedAccounts] for entity [Account]*

The scratch org definition has the ServiceCloud and LightningServiceConsole features included but I can't even see this list view when logged into the scratch org UI.

It deploys just fine in a sandbox where I can see the list view in the UI so it leads me to believe i'm missing something in the scratch org definition file but I can't find anything in features or settings that makes a difference.

p.s. i'm using sfdx command *sfdx force:source:push*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new Dynamic Forms functionality in your source org, make sure you have enabled dynamic forms in the scratch org

Comment: Hi @Melissa, thanks for the reply, couple of things; 
1) I had this enabled anyway in the scratch org definition (using recordPageSettings > enableDynamicForms) 
2) the reason it is failing is because the standard ListView can't be found 
3) it the page was designed before dynamic forms where released meaning there should be no use of dynamic form functions.